# why my render result different from render preview（problem has been solved）

Tags: rendering

this is the render preview
[image]

this is the render result
[image]

Why is a part of the screw missing

this is my blend file
[link to blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3OWYr-7wLGzOHDAPiVY_CpwzMVxXXCp/view?usp=share_link)

thanks to Alexandre Marcati.
I change the setting.rendering set to GPU.and it is ok now.
[image]

Comment: weird because it works fine for me

Comment: (｡•́︿•̀｡)(;´༎ຶД༎ຶ`)T^T

Comment: Also works fine for me. Very weird. I noticed the rendering was set to CPU and not GPU. If you have a GPU try changing it.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Amazing,I change setting.rendering set to GPU.and it is ok now.thank you.just take a very long to render.

Comment: Usually GPU renders faster than CPU, but I guess it depends on the GPU/CPU.

Comment: MacBook is not the best choice for 3D.(｡•́︿•̀｡)ㄟ(▔ ,▔)ㄏ(⑉꒦ິ^꒦ິ⑉)